# Occasional yet persistent 500 internal server errors

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-500

I'm at my wits end with this.

I have a WordPress site with a few (7) plugins and I am getting around 10 reports a day of 500 Internal Server Errors.

These could happen at any time whether just browsing the site or via the administration part of the site.

I have contacted the host and just tell me that they are not developers and that there is a problem with the site, which is no help at all. Surely if there were an issue with the site/code it would manifest itself permanently not just randomly.

The only meaningful error I have found from around the same time these 500 errors occur is:

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47767] End of script output before headers: index.php
mysite.com [Mon Jan 04 15:31:57 2016] [error]

Which, from searches, could mean pretty much anything. The only thing I've also found is that some of the code may contain whitespace, but surely this can't occur only occasionally? It would happen all the time.

This happens on the main index page which doesn't change. Am I being fed lies from the host? Why does it only happen occasionally on a page that doesn't change?

I'm tempted to move the site to another host to prove a point, but am also happy to be proven wring and there is something wrong with the site, rather than the (shared) server it runs on.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have contacted the host and just tell me that they are not
>   developers and that there is a problem with the site, which is no help
>   at all. Surely if there were an issue with the site/code it would
>   manifest itself permanently not just randomly.

500 Server Errors can be difficult to track down. But, if they are transient and not consistent, I'd say the host is flakey, esp. if they are not much help.

Find another host with an inexpensive, money-back guarantee and copy the site over and test it for a few days.

If you leave the current site up and use a spare domain or an IP on the new host, you need to change URLs in the database for the site copy on the new host. See [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: This indeed turned out to be an issue with the host. I moved the site elsewhere to test and the problems went away, I moved it back and they came back, the host moved me to a different server and all is OK now. Problem : server overloaded. Thanks